# How to convert Japanese half/full width characters using ICU Library

Tags: java, unicode, icu

i am not too familiar with java (coming from c++/c#). I have a need for to use java in order to convert some documents from halfwidth japanese charaters to full width.

would someone be kind and provide some example to start with. i have not had luck to finding some sample.

just a note it has to be in Java.

Comment: Note: ICU stands for International Components for Unicode.  The I hasn't meant IBM (exclusively) for a decade or so.

Answer (score 3):

Found this on [Japanese blogger Arai's site](http://karaiblog.blog45.fc2.com/blog-entry-146.html):

```
String data1 = "全角ひらがな"; // full-width hiragana
String data2 = "全角カタカナ"; // full-width katakana
String data3 = "半角ｶﾀｶﾅ";    // half-width katakana

Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Hiragana-Katakana");

System.out.println(transliterator.transliterate(data1));
System.out.println(transliterator.transliterate(data2));
System.out.println(transliterator.transliterate(data3));
```

This should result in all 3 Japanese strings being transliterated as you would expect. Give this a shot a let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted hiragana to be changed; it sounds like he wanted `Halfwidth-Fullwidth`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Daniel. I was only providing an example for the OP to start working with, and Arai-san's example just happened to convert from Hiragana to Katakana. I figured the person asking the question would be able to figure out where to go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [ICU userguide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general%20ICU%20userguide) and [ICU APIdoc](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html) on the topic? You can use the [Transliterator demo](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit) to check the behavior, such as "Halfwidth-Fullwidth"

Comment: oh thank you for the demo. i have read the api and created the Filter Rules to convert but was not successful. the demo should help!

Comment: Thanks @Steven.It helped lot in my Android project.Nice One +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small, simple library to handle all types of kana conversion in Java, [details here](http://mariten.github.io/kanatools-java/en/kana-converter/)

To convert from half-width to full-width, just download the JAR and then write the code like this:

```
import mariten.kanatools.KanaConverter;

// rest of code...

String half_width = "半角ｶﾀｶﾅ";

int conv_flags = KanaConverter.OP_HAN_KATA_TO_ZEN_KATA;
String full_width = KanaConverter.convertKana(half_width, conv_flags);

System.out.println(full_width)
//半角カタカナ
```